# Pandas Outer Merge Column Sequence is not Fixed

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to merge two data frames using pandas. 
I am doing outer merge of the data frames. My data frame has following columns:

```
DF1: (ID, X)
DF2: (ID, Y, Z)
```

when i merge these data frames, the sequence of columns in the output data frame changes.

For some iterations i get

```
DF_OUTPUT: (ID, X, Y, Z)
```

or sometimes it is:

```
DF_OUTPUT: (X, ID, Y, Z)
```

How can i preserve the sequence of columns in the output data frame?

Comment: Are you certain the order in `DF1` is always `(ID, X)` and not `(X, ID)`

Comment: @ALollz Yes I am sure about that. But the solution that you suggested worked

Answer (score 2):

You can `.reindex` after the merge. Use `pd.unique` which will preserve the order of occurrence, unlike `np.unique` which sorts.

```
import pandas as pd

cols = pd.unique(df1.columns.append(df2.columns))
df1.merge(df2, how='outer').reindex(cols, axis=1)
```